# What is Poly-valency?

Tags: chords

I recently heard of something called "poly-valency" which wikipedia describes as being two harmonic functions from the same key played simultaneously. Does that mean playing the I and V  chords simultaneously, or the alternatively, the ii and vi chords simultaneously?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that if polyvalency is two harmonic functions being played simultaneously, then that means two types of chords are being played at once.

The types of chords I mean are Tonic function (I, iii, and vi), Subdominant function (ii, IV) and Dominant Function (V, viio). So for example, a polyvalent structure could have a Dm chord at the same time as an Am chord (in C major), because the Dm has Subdominant function but the Am has tonic function. Another example would be playing an A at the same time as an E7 (Tonic vs Dominant functions).